# How do I get the File Extention for a Mime Type (Content Type)

Tags: java, mime-types, file-extension

There are tons of ways to get the Mime Type from a given InputStream or File.
But given a MimeType or (in HTTP terms: content type) how do I get a list of file extensions.

Java's activation library has 
MimetypesFileTypeMap but that goes File Ext -> Mime Type. I need Mime Type -> File Ext.

It seems like I would have to copy the pseudo private code that is in com.sun.activation to load up the mime type mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Java Mimeutil library which comes with [mime-types.properties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/eu.medsea.mimeutil/mime-util/2.1/eu/medsea/mimeutil/mime-types.properties?av=f) file that you can load.

Comment: Use the ExtensionMimeDetector class

Answer (score 0):

Apache comes with a [mime.types](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.0.x/docs/conf/mime.types) file. You could parse this file and use it to map filename extensions to content types and vice versa. This file is located in the `Apache Group/Apache2/conf` directory.